# Маршрутизация: после отправки данных на сервер вернуться на эту же страницу

Tags: маршрутизация, kohana

Здравствуйте. Не могу найти пример кода для Kohana, суть в том, что нужно после отправки данных на сервер  - вернуться на эту же страницу. Приведите пример если можно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если 3.2, то

```
$this->request->redirect($this->request->referrer());
```

В 3.3

```
$this->redirect($this->request->referrer());
```